# How to save String Array to Core Data in Swift

Tags: ios, arrays, swift3, save, swift4

I need to save my String Array to Core Data.

```
let stringArray: [String] = ["First String", "Second String", "Third String"]
```

I have 1 Attributes with the type String. I have tried that, but it doesn't work.

```
let entityCoreData = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObject(forEntityName: "Hadith", into: context)

entityCoreData.setValue(firstEntity, forKey: "firstAttribute")

do {
    try context.save()
} catch {
    print("issue by saving data")
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add Entity in .xcDataModel as "Hadith" & add 1 attribute as "value" type of string.
Now select that entity & from Editor Menu -> Create NSManagedObject class

Save data in entity

```
let appDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
    let context = appDelegate.managedObjectContext

    for str in strinArray {
        do {
            let newitem = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName("Hadith", inManagedObjectContext: context)
            newitem.setValue(str,forKey: "value")
            try context.save()
        } catch {
            //do nothing
        }
```

Comment: this will insert whole new object when trying to save just one element of the array